# Getting Kivy running with Python on Winpython

Tags: python, kivy

I've done tons of research on my issues, and I haven't really found an answer:
I'm trying to use Kivy in Eclipse on my computer. I've got an environment setup already, and I installed Kivy and the dependencies just like this: 
https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#

I copied the first bit of code from the tutorial on their site which should simply make a blank window, and upon running I got this error:

```
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
...
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Just from that, I found tons of people with the same issue. issue 3002 on kivy's github (sorry, I can't put too many links) suggests solutions for linux users, which doesn't help me.

This: [Trying to run KIVY, for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113270/trying-to-run-kivy-for-the-first-time) suggests installing pygame, which I've done multiple times, but it looks like the last update for pygame was in 2009? (I looked at their main site)

Either way, I installed pygame and that didn't change a thing. I also looked at issue 3491 (again, can't post more than 2 links) which seems very applicable but suggests downloading drivers from my GPU vendor, which I have no idea how to do, or what GPU I even have.

Is there any solution to my problem? Do I have to try and figure out how to get correct drivers? Also, I am using WinPython if that matters, but it seems to work for everything else...

Comment: Kivy no longer uses pygame. Did you install Kivy and its dependencies following the Windows instructions [here](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#install-win-dist)?

Comment: This error relates to missing SDL2 components, it probably isn't the GPU driver problem you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Paste output of `echo %PATH%` here. Feel free to cut of personal things, I only want to know if sdl2 is available on the path (which I think is not). If not, add it. Should look like this:

```
<python.exe dir>\share\sdl2\bin
```

If it doesn't work for you, well... I'm still sure it's deps & path-related error. I usually annoy people with a link to my installer's github repo when I see similar error. I have there [this line](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller/blob/master/kivy.bat#L350):

```
set PATH=%~dp0;%~dp0Tools;%~dp0Scripts;%~dp0share\sdl2\bin;%~dp0Lib\idlelib;%PATH%
```

Put `<python dir>\Scripts` on path too, because of `garden`, `pip` and other stuff.