# python kivy installation in virtual environment returns already installed but doesn't import

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

**I'm looking for**
installing Kivy in a virtual environment created in Anaconda for python 2.7

I have been through the following references:

- [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550813/python-kivy-installation-error-in-ubuntu-16-04)
- [two](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash/issues/39)
- [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113270/trying-to-run-kivy-for-the-first-time)

perhaps, they didn't work for me.

Here's the output I see, that confuses me:

```
(py27anc) mister-t@BrightMachine:~/PycharmProjects/StockAnalysisGUI$ sudo apt-get install python-kivy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-kivy is already the newest version (1.9.0-3build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

(py27anc) mister-t@BrightMachine:~/PycharmProjects/StockAnalysisGUI$ which python
/home/mister-t/anaconda3/envs/py27anc/bin/python

(py27anc) mister-t@BrightMachine:~/PycharmProjects/StockAnalysisGUI$ python
Python 2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import kivy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named kivy
```

**Besides this**
I tried doing it via IDE (PyCharm). Returns Error beyond my grasp.
I installed necessary packages for same especially the Cython library, yet fails.

[image: Package installation fails]
Also, note I tried with Pip, Upgraded pip to latest version and retried. Created new Virtual ENV and tried all over again and yet fails.

Comment: When you are in venv, *py27anc* do the following: (1) *conda install pip*, (2) *pip install cython==0.25.2*, and (3) *pip install kivy*

Comment: @ikolim the 1st command itself has failed saying `Solving environment: failed`, It has printed a huge error report with it. any more ideas?

Comment: At terminal command prompt, execute *conda install -n py27anc pip*